# Bukkit plugin throws error

Tags: bukkit

So i wrote a Bukkit plugin that, throws an error in console but anything works
COnsole Log:

```html
 [10:28:19 INFO]: [INTGlobalPlugin] Enabling INTGlobalPlugin v1.0
[10:28:19 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling INTGlobalPlugin v1.0 (Is it                     up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at me.intglobal.plugin.Main.onEnable(Main.java:20) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:329) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:401) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:361) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:323) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:723) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:534) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:622) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1326) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1186) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:37) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:9) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:46) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:695) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:366) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:650) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:554) [CrraftBukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-bb4ae3b]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

how can i fic this?

Comment: Post your code, specifically your `onEnable`. Do you think we are mind readers?

Comment: How exactly should anyone help you fix your code if we don't know it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `at me.intglobal.plugin.Main.onEnable(Main.java:20) ~[?:?]` means you should check line 20 in your `Main.java`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put it in the src/ folder, but in the project folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception means, that you are trying to use some variable that is null (nothing). This problem is on 20th line of your Main file. Maybe you are trying to use the logger, but you forgot to set it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException, which means that whatever variable you've created in your code, doesn't have anything to hold. If you'd like to fix this maybe initialize it or just add something into the variable.